# Outputting to DVI port

Tags: frame, sequential, dvi

I am attempting to program a frame sequential 3D signal to an eMagin z800 HMD. This unit communicates via a VGA serial port however I am using a NVidia Quadro FX 3450/4000 SDI graphics card which has only DVI ports. Therefore I have connected it via a VGA-DVI converter.

I am wandering if anyone has any help with outputting to the DVI port in c# (as that is what the rest of my base program is written in) ideally sending an image. Alternatively any experience and help in programming with the z800 would be appreciated.

Thanks